# Changing some string by awk

Tags: string, awk, data-manipulation

I have a big file here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujesog1yv5yzbes/vep.txt?dl=0

From this file I need something like

```
Uploaded_variation  Chromosome  Location    Ref Allele  gene
1_3407069_C/T            1      3407069      C     T    C1orf159
1_26226650_G/A           1     26226650      G     A    C1orf159
1_41950247_C/T           1     41950247      C     T    C1orf159
```

A sample of my desired file is here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vnhng5vno11ct1/WHAT_I_need.txt?dl=0

I found this script that gives me some part of my desired output but with a mess

```
awk '{split($1,a,"_"); split(a[3],b,"/"); print a[1],a[2],b[1],b[2],$0}' file.vep.txt | awk '{split($18,a,";"); split(a[2],b,"="); print b[2],$0}'> Jane_script_output.txt
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6sjucbrb49l93xl/Jane_script_output.txt?dl=0

In this output by this script I have

```
 #Uploaded variation   #Uploaded_variation
 1 883477 G T 1_883477_G/T
PRDM16 1 3125744 A G 1_3125744_A/G
PRDM16 1 3125744 A G 1_3125744_A/G
PRDM16 1 3125744 A G 1_3125744_A/G
```

I don't know how to this script to give me column wise output also instead of this mess

Comment: Why would you only accept a bash or R answer, and not, say, an awk answer? It's better to just specify the goal, and not try to dictate tools... though it's *better than that* to show your own attempt, so you're asking someone how to solve a problem with your own effort, not just asking someone to write a program for you (which we generally refuse to do).

Comment: BTW -- how many entries does each file have, and how are they separated? It's very different to be transforming a file that's only one record long, vs one of arbitrary length. Be sure you're providing everything that might be needed to make a testable answer.

Comment: Also, make sure your input and output precisely match each other. This looks like they're about completely different symbols.

Comment: To repeat myself: Make sure your output shown in the question is what you expect the program to print **when given your sample input**. Surely you don't expect it to take `SYMBOL=NOC2L` as input and output `SYMBOL=C1orf159`? If we don't have byte-for-byte correct expected output from given input as part of the question, how can anyone be sure that they're correctly testing their answers?

Comment: Similarly, if your input file has more than one input record in practice, make sure that's true for the sample input and sample output, so folks building answers know how the boundaries between different records will behave. This is still not likely to be well-received, insofar as it's asking for someone to do your work for you instead of asking how to solve a specific problem you encountered while trying to do your own work, but at least that would make it *answerable*, even if it's in violation of other rules.

Comment: Thank you I correct that

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing that your input file is **really** complete chaos a shown in your question with random white space and line breaks all over the place and apparently different numbers of fields in each line and what looks like header text mixed in with the data in some lines. Please check to make sure that the sample input you provide in your question is **exactly** the input you need to process. and either post the corrected version or tell us if it really is a total mess like that.

Comment: The reference file you uploaded looks absolutely nothing like the sample input you provided, the real data is apparently simply one record of space-separated fields per line which is trivial to process. Just copy/paste a couple of lines of THAT into your question in place of the mess that's currently there as your sample input and provide the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer as below may help more people

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{split($1,a,"_"); split(a[3],b,"/"); print a[1],a[2],b[1],b[2],$0}' file.vep.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{split($18,a,";"); split(a[2],b,"="); print b[2],$0}' > newfile.txt
```

Comment: Is this your answer to the problem, or another attempt that requires further assistance? Please edit it to describe what readers are looking at. Thanks!